# How do I run Popcorn-time / Flixtor?

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded the `.tar.gz` and extracted the files to desktop.

I clicked on Popcorn-time / Flixtor but nothing opens.

I allowed "Run as executable" , and tried running from Terminal ( Gives me `"File not found error"`)

Comment: post the command you tried.

Comment: I cd-ed into Popcorn-Time folder and Did /.<filename> ( i double checked)

Comment: `/.command` isn't the correct way, is `./command`. Please, [edit] your post and paste the complete procedure you are following

Answer (score 0):

To most, its just double click the file. That said there is a lib issue.

- For  32-bit systems:

  ```
  sudo ln -sf /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
  ```
- For  64-bit systems:

  ```
  sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
  ```

**Source**:

- [The solution of lacking libudev.so.0 · rogerwang/node-webkit Wiki](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/The-solution-of-lacking-libudev.so.0)

Comment: I'm unable to use that command , it asks me for my sudo password and I type it in and it's doesn't do anything. If I press enter, it leaves the thing